# Files written from chrome packaged apps are all empty

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

## The Problem

I am trying output a file from a Chrome Packaged app (using chrome.fileSystem) that I am developing, but all the files are being saved are being created, but with no content no matter what I do. I have researched this for hours and can only seem to find people using the same basic code that I am, and that I can't get to run. Am I missing something obvious here? Is this code running for everyone else, and I should just try to run it on a friends computer? Any help would be appreciated!

## What I Have Done So Far:

I am using the code below (from the [Chrome developer documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage)) in one of my javascript files to try and write some text to a file that the user specifies. As far as I can tell, this should write "1234567890" to whichever file I specify when I run the program, but all of the files are being created properly, but they don't have any content.

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'saveFile'}, function(writableFileEntry) {
writableFileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
  writer.onerror = errorHandler;
  writer.onwriteend = function(e) {
    console.log('write complete');
  };
  writer.write(new Blob(['1234567890'], {type: 'text/plain'}));
}, errorHandler);
});
```

I have also set the following permissions in my manifest.json file:

```
"permissions": [
    {"fileSystem": ["write"]}
]
```

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Do you have an `errorHandler` function defined? If so, what error does it get? If not, that could be your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I forgot to add an error handler. As soon as I added that it started working! Can I accept that as an answer or not since it's only a comment? I can't see how to add it, and this is my first question, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `errorHandler` function isn't defined, that could be the problem. Your code would then crash after the file was created but before the blob was written to it.

Comment: Thanks again! That was a big help!